# How can i setup read permission in spool email for root in linux

Tags: linux, centos, permissions

I am using nagios to read the file `/var/spool/mail/root` because i have some errors in email then know what is the problem.

I have setup the ownership to `root:nagios`.

but any time when root write to that file , then it changes the permission back to `rw-------`

i have to manually change it but again root changes it back

what should i do

Comment: By "errors in email", do you mean problems with your email subsystem, or email that you have received about errors with some other subsystem?

Comment: @MadHatter . i am using amazon SES with sendmail . at Amazon i need to verify email before sending. sometimes if emails is not verified i get error mail in `spool/root` which says email address not verified so that i can know that there is error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, you're getting emails from some automated system into root's local spool warning of errors with some other subsystem (email authentication), and you want NAGIOS to be able to look for those.  Presumably, you've got or written some NAGIOS plugin that checks root's email spool for these; let's call it `check_root_mbox`.

The issue is ensuring that the plugin has the right permissions to read the mailbox file, which you've been trying to do by adjusting the ownership of root's mail spool file.  That's probably not the best way to do this.

Either you need to run the plugin under `sudo`, or you need to modify the original jobs that generate these errors so that the replies come to somewhere other than `root@localhost`.  The latter is beyond the scope of this answer, as you've told us nothing about the jobs that generate these bounces.

If you go for the former, it has two steps; running the plugin under sudo, and having sudo permit it.

To do the first part, if you're running under NRPE, put some line like

```
command[check_root_mbox]=sudo /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_root_mbox
```

in your `nrpe.cfg`, adjusting paths accordingly.  If you're running NAGIOS on the system itself, put a `check_command` such as

```
define command{
        command_name    check_root_mbox
        command_line    /usr/bin/sudo $USER1$/check_root_mbox
        }
```

in your config, and use it.  Then for the second part, put a line like

```
nagios  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_root_mbox
```

in your `sudoers` file, again adjusting paths accordingly.

Comment: when u put `/usr/lib...` after `NOPASSWD` Does it mean that system will ask no password for that command but if nagios try to execute anything else with sudo then it will ask for password

Comment: Half-right; it means that nagios will be able to sudo that command without being prompted for a password, but that it won't be allowed to execute anything else via sudo no matter what password it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try it this way. Your SMTP server (whatever one you use)  has diagnose commands that will tell you (and nagios) if there are problems. Reading a spool file is not a way to learn about the status of it.

Comment: i am using sendmail and `maillog` does not show me relevant error message. i am using amazon `aws-email` for sending emails via sendmail

Comment: Use `check_smtp` and maybe some specialized sendmail plugin. `mailq` should show you the state of the mail queue.